# Google chrome fonts not work well

Tags: css

Hi all I have this code and google chrome can't render fonts :(

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'carial';
src: url('./fonts/bpg.eot');
src: url('./fonts/bpg.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('./fonts/bpg.woff') format('woff'), 
url('./fonts/bpg.ttf') format('truetype'), 
url('./fonts/bpg.svg#bpg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

[image] 
^^ chrome

[image]
firefox
[image]

explorer

Comment: Are you sure that Georgian glyphs are included in the font file? When testing the font in Google fonts, paste in the string and if nothing appears, that means no. However, your computer will render them in the default font for Georgian set by your PC.

Comment: What is the question? “Can't render fonts” does not describe a problem, when the image clearly contains text in some font(s).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that it's not compulsory that font can work properly to all browser...
and our responsibility is that we should be check manually on all majorly used browsers.

If not working in any browsers then we can make new font face from new website. We can make font face from diff-2 font face generator website. You can search on the Google with this keyword...."font face generator" and will get more link for this related.